# Remove all elements from a nested list

Tags: python

How can I remove all elements from a nested list.

I have a list

```
exlines =  ['BT--45', 'BX--W45']
```

and a nested list

```
Node= ['BSTP12', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],
['BX--34', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],
['QDVPLF', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],   
['BT--89', 'F5 Inc.', 'Directory exists'], 
['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['MWL03', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['MWL04', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
['BEWL01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['BEWL02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['BEIPT01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['BEIPT02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['MADP03', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['MADP04', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
['NLBX--D2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['NLBT--D1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['BT--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['NLBT--DW2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['NLBX--DW1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['BX--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists']

for regel in exlines:
    nested_remove(Node, regel)

def nested_remove(L, x):
    if x in L
        L.remove(x)
    else:
        for element in L:
            if type(element) is list:
                nested_remove(element, x)
```

This only removed **BT--45** (and **BX--45**) from Node list but not 'CP' and 'Directory exists'

This lines must be removed from Node

```
['BT--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
['BX--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists']
```

Comment: "This lines must be removed from Node" - They were never even in there, so you can't remove them.

Comment: @KellyBundy - yes they were - check the last and fourth-last lines in Node

Comment: Note that you should have brackets around all of the sublists in `Node`.

Comment: [No they're not.](https://tio.run/##rdNPC4IwGAbwu5/ivVmQkbqoDh2qJQgWiySD6BAp6cXJXJCf3nyhIircDt12@PE8@/OuqGTKc3dciLpe8ziZwsGcb0NmO2YPTG8Ifn7u49IhkPKrKOF04eaxZzRsb1kuUbIN3bHAa2cAgIGhZY0nH5JmIjlLLipIblkpS9Rol14UDGwUCwaBjHE1gvhUvTJfytFS/8laNcbVMETZ9r2l@HkV78ZRGZ@F6iBEiqTVjLLPo/00pN2sAxwc@mhreeIGNgNBbSVERoa6eZFWM24x0qjeq6oNoxBZLjv4ubp1fQc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward. Let's use a list comprehension to generate a *new* list *without* the sublists you want to avoid.

```
exlines =  ['BT--45', 'BX--W45']

Node = [
 ['BSTP12', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],
 ['BX--34', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],
 ['QDVPLF', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],   
 ['BT--89', 'F5 Inc.', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['MWL03', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['MWL04', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'], 
 ['BEWL01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['BEWL02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['BEIPT01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['BEIPT02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['MADP03', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['MADP04', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'], 
 ['NLBX--D2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['NLBT--D1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['BT--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['NLBT--DW2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['NLBX--DW1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'], 
 ['BX--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists']]

[sublist for sublist in Node
         if not any(ex in sublist for ex in exlines)]
```

Result:

```
[['BSTP12', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'], 
 ['BX--34', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'], 
 ['QDVPLF', 'F5 Inc.', '24 hours ago'],
 ['BT--89', 'F5 Inc.', 'Directory exists'],
 ['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['BEFWL01', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['BEFWL02', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['MWL03', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['MWL04', 'CP Ltd', '7 days ago'],
 ['BEWL01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['BEWL02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['BEIPT01', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['BEIPT02', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['MADP03', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['MADP04', 'CP Ltd', 'directory'],
 ['NLBX--D2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'],
 ['NLBT--D1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'],
 ['NLBT--DW2', 'CP', 'Directory exists'],
 ['NLBX--DW1', 'CP', 'Directory exists'],
 ['BX--45', 'CP', 'Directory exists']]
```

Comment: @Hans If you feel this answered your question, you can accept Chris's answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.